# Is there a place to get critique on questions in order to hone them?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm looking for critique on whether something is a valid question.  Is there a way to get feedback and test a question before posting and having my reputation slaughtered?  For instance, I changed the wording of a question here: [How to build a JSON file with nested records from a flat data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713329/use-python-to-build-nested-json-from-flat-table) , but only after it had already been knocked out of the ballpark for being too broad earlier.

Comment: Depends.... You want help on a good, on topic question, that you validated against the help center.... Or you want help on your question's first draft? (Just saying that since the first version of the linked question is.... Oooofffffff). Anyway, meta is a good place for that kind of things. Just make sure your post follows the rules. Like on the main site, it is YOUR responsiblity to abide by the rules and standards as much as possible. Posting good questions you want help with,but you know are on topic, is good. Asking us how to make any question you have on topic? Bad.

Comment: You're in the right place.  And, once you get enough rep, you can throw it into pastebin and ask for help in relevant chat rooms.

Comment: @Will, good to know. I wasn't aware of [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) before.

Comment: @Will GitHub gists are also nice, especially as they support markdown.

Comment: Geez these are some prickly answers. For me, having the perfect artisanally crafted question off the hop is a rarity - there is always going to be some rewriting, some clarification needed. I think your question was downvoted not necessarily because of the detail, but because it's very specific - it's hard to imagine how others would find it useful without having _exactly_ the same data schema.

Comment: But generally speaking, I would want any question I looked at to at least appear as if the author had spent some time thinking not just about the question, but also the info that a person attempting to answer it would require (even if it's just a guess). Chat rooms / meta can be good places to ask for help as mentioned, especially if you're not sure why your questions isn't doing as well as you had hoped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Travis has said, the answer is "No, there is no place to get a critique on a question prior to posting it."

However, there are chat rooms filled with skilled and experienced users. Such chat rooms can be a great resource for anyone with >20 rep. If you're in doubt whether a question is off topic, too broad or maybe a duplicate of another question, ask in an appropriate chat room.

I have asked if there are any relevant questions covering what I'm trying to do several times, and have always received help, and not a single comment saying I'm in the wrong place.

> I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in [hard-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-language). I have tried to convert the string to a boolean list, and count the numbers of `true`-values. `sum(str == 's')` gives an error `"'bool' object is not iterable"`. I haven't found a relevant question, but I would think it has been asked before. Does anyone know if this has been covered in a question already? If not, is this considered an on-topic question?

---

Of course you have to adapt this to your question, which might be more complex. Don't paste 30 lines of codes an expect people in chat to read through it all though. In general, people are not in chat rooms to answer questions.

> Hi! I'm looking for a python technique to build a nested JSON file from a flat table in a pandas data frame. Is it OK to ask a question such as: "How could a pandas dataframe table be taken and exported to a JSON that looks like [format]? If not, is there a way I can make this an on-topic question?

(Don't include the [format]. It's not relevant in the chat post.)

You will likely get one out of two answers:

> Yes, this is on-topic. Note that you should include a [mcve], and the code you have tried so far. Please include a good explanation of what you're trying to achieve, and where you're stuck.

Or

> No, this is too broad / unclear. Please try to be more specific. You must at least include an explanation of what you have tried so far, explain exactly where you're stuck, and what you want to achieve. Check out [ask] and [help:on-topic]. You should also include a [mcve].

Answer (score 30):

No, there is no place to get a critique on a question prior to posting it.

Questions are expected to have been carefully crafted prior to posting and are examined in their current state by users (not their future state or potential state).

There are many places to look for guidance at Stack Overflow and elsewhere with regards to how to compose a question and how to specifically compose a programming related question here at the site that is on topic. For example

- The "*How To Ask*" page at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- Jon Skeet's "*Writing The Perfect Question*" at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/
- "*How to create an MCVE*" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Most of these boil down to creating a question while looking at the standpoint of someone answering it. Is all of the relevant information there? Is irrelevant information excluded? Is there a proper explanation of what is known, what is expected, and what actually happened? What would an answer look like to this question?

The only feedback available is going to be after the question is posted as far as Stack Overflow goes. With this under consideration, be mindful of the state of the question posted - do not post a rough draft.

Comment: `Questions(...) are examined in their current state by users (not their future state or potential state).` Doesn't this make editing them trying to fix them frustatingly hopeless? I mean, if I worded it poorly and got -15, wouldn't I be better off deleting it and retrying with a new question than editing it? That feels... wrong! Would it be nuts to come up with some criteria to, after a heavy edit, "reset" the vote score, or mark it as "reworded" to give it another fighting chance?

Comment: Daizu, that would be a nice feature request but until then, deleting is the best option. Or just deal with it. After all, 15 downvotes = -30 points which is easily compensated by getting just 3 upvotes on a good answer.

Comment: [Community Wiki says no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Nope. A downvote is worth -2 points, not -5.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm looking for critique on whether something is a valid question. Is there a way to get feedback and test a question before posting and having my reputation slaughtered?

Yes, you can ask on meta or in chat to check with the community if something is on-topic.  This is a very basic test of something being on-topic.  If you ask a meta question, post your proposed question inside the body.  Possible meta-tags include [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation), [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), and even [too-broad](/questions/tagged/too-broad).  As an example, the body your meta question could look like:

> I have a question in python that I think is on-topic, but maybe it is
>   too broad.  If my question is not on-topic, why and what could I do to
>   fix it?
>
> Here's my question:
>
> `<insert your question here>`
>
> [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)[too-broad](/questions/tagged/too-broad)

---

You shouldn't have to do this too often, but it's fine before asking questions that you feel are borderline.  Do not use this to avoid a question ban on the main site, and be prepared for the answer that your question is indeed off-topic and even unsalvageable.  And try not to abuse the meta effect to get your question more views.  For example, if your question turns out to be on-topic, avoid providing a link to the meta question after the fact.

Answer (score -10):

Your question has been reopened by 5 votes. So seems like all users don't really agree if your question is on topic or not.

In my opinion your questions is on topic and is not even a low quality one because:

- The question is clear: "my code is not working as expected how can I fix it"
- You have searched by yourself before posting here
- You give us every elements that we need to be able to answer: the code, the current result, the desired result.

And I disagree with the comment saying "a high level approach". However your problem is not only about python but with the algorithm to be used too this may be why this question was closed on the first hand.

Comment: Please do capitalize the letter i when referring to yourself, and generally there should be no space before punctuation like the colon.

Comment: The fact that it was reopened doesn't mean that there's disagreement over the question, it means that the edits to the question actually addressed the problems with it.

Comment: This doesn't address the question "Is there a place to get critique on questions in order to hone them?"